# Summing a few items in a integer list

Tags: python, julian-date

So I've searched quite a bit but haven't found something exactly similar to my question. My question is: I have a list of days in months. It looks like this:

```py
daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

now, I already have a leap year formula that works out to change `daysInMonth[1]` to `29` if it is a leapyear.

I need to sum up a select number of values in my list based on the user's entry of month.  the reason for this, is the julian day is the number of days in the year to the date entered.  so the user enters a date such as `1 31 2020`, and the julian day would be: `31`, so `2 2 2020` would be: `33`, and `12 31 2020` would be: `366` because its a leap year this year.  Hopefully that makes sense.

I did this project back in high school on C++ and I'm trying to convert it to Python. The C++ version of what I'm trying to do looks like this:

```py
int findingTheMonth(int daysInMonth[], int julianDay, int day, int month)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (month-1); i++)
    {
        julianDay = julianDay + daysInMonth[i];
    }
    julianDay = julianDay + day;

    return julianDay;
}
```

My version in Python was this:

```py
def findTheJulian(day, month, daysInMonth):
    # sum together the months up until the users entered month
    # then add the amount of days of the users entered month
    julianDay = sum(daysInMonth[month-1]) + day

    return julianDay
```

The reason this fails is because it says int object not iterable, but I don't understand why its giving me this. I'm not trying to change an integer or write over an integer... I'm trying to store a new value into julianDay by summing up a few elements of a list, and the users entered day.. What do I do? Also, I'm brand new in Python. There may be a lot of things that I don't quite understand yet, but I have a coding background and should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Your python code has 3 parameters while C++ one has 4? What are those?

Comment: you probably want to change ```daysInMonth[month-1]``` to ```daysInMonth[:month-1]```. see the ```:``` added. you want sum of a list not of in integer

Comment: i didnt need to bring in julianDay because its not defined in my main code.  i define julianDay here and return it back to my main code and immediately print it out.

Comment: Use a Python for loop and in that just like in c++ code   julianDay = julianDay + daysInMonth[i]

Comment: @YashShah `daysInMonth[:month]` would be correct.

Comment: @blhsing i think OP doesnt want ```month``` included in list. hence i suggested ```month-1``` maybe you are right. OP's decision

Comment: @YashShah `daysInMonth[:month]` excludes the value at the index of `month` already. It's how slicing works in Python.

Comment: @blhsing I'm sorry my bad. OP doesnt want ```month-1``` in the list according to the c++ code. Note the < sign in for loop not <=.

Comment: @YashShah Good point. `month` must start from 1 in this case then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are taking one element from daysInMonth. As example, if you pass `daysInMonth == [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]` and `month == 3` you get `31`. And `sum(31)` raises error because you can't get sum of a number.

The goal you want to reach is taking a slice of a list (all elements before `month`). Slice syntax is `list[start:end]`. You can ignore `start` and set only `end`, then `start` will be 0.

Your case: `julianDay = sum(daysInMonth[:month-1]) + day`

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, i will go study so more on slicing lists,  thank you, and yes the code worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

`daysInMonth[month-1]` gets you a specific value from daysInMonth. What you want to do is `daysInMonth[:month-1]` (note the colon). This gets you a slice of daysInMonth, which `sum()` is then able to iterate over.